# firebase receive JSON via HTTP request

Tags: arrays, json, database, firebase, lua

firebase:
how to get remote config information via HTTP in the form of a JSON request, without modules?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pl230.png)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Remote Config provides REST endpoints you can use to get your project's remote config. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/remote-config/rest